# Travelling to France for vacation with a single-entry India visa

Tags: visas, schengen, india, cameroonian-citizens

I am a foreign student studying in India for 2 years. I have a single-entry visa and I wish to go for a vacation in France at the end of June 2018.

First, I want to know about the possibility to get a Schengen visa since I have a single-entry Indian Student visa, and second, will it be possible to get a visa to return to India after the vacation?

Comment: What nationality are you? You are on a single-entry-student visa in India?

Comment: i am from cameroon!

Comment: Yes i have got a single-entry student visa when i was coming India!

Comment: I also wanted to change my visa , but there is no ambassy no consulate as well of cameroon in India that was the Problem.

Comment: You wanted to change your India visa while in India? That would be a matter for the Indian government. Why would you need a Cameroon consulate?

Comment: I wanted to change it to a multiple entry infact!

Comment: @h.cedric You don't do that at the Cameroonian consulate, because they cannot do anything with Indian visas. You Need to visit the Bureau of Immigration in India

Comment: I need a cameroon  consulate bcs my passport going to expire in august 2019 and will need to renew or extend it. And i will still be here.

Answer (score 0):

You must go to the Indian [Bureau of Immigration](https://boi.gov.in/) and apply to Change your visa to a multiple-entry one.

Then you can apply for a Schengen visa at the French embassy/consulate